# How to get the area of the trapezoid?

Tags: geometry

I have the following basic geometry exercise, but I only know 3 sides. And I must not solve it with trigonometry.

[image]

Well, with trigonometry it is trivial. But with the formula of the trapeze area, I can not get the height.

So, How can I get the area? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn’t possible to solve this without the use of trigonometry.  You must use trigo to solve for the height

Comment: A trapezoid has a pair of parallel lines. Maybe you can try to cut it into parts.

Comment: poyea, can you help me in that? i already tried it..

Comment: The height of the trapezium is $BC\sin 30^\circ=6$. If you abhor trigonometry you can derive this by drawing a suitable equilateral triangle.

Comment: Extend to get a triangle. EAB which is similar to EDC.  Use similarity to figure out what EB is (you'll get a quadratic equation $EB = EC + CB$ and $\frac {EB}{CB} = \frac {AB}{DC}$.)  Then drop a perpendicular down from $E$.  You will have a 30-60-90 triange with a known hypotenuse.  The heightt will be half that.  The height of the trapezoid will be proportional.

Comment: "It isn’t possible to solve this without the use of trigonometry. "  You don't need trig for a 30-60-90 triangle.

Comment: Argh.... just drop the perpendicular from $C$.  As that forms a 30-60-90 triangle the height is just $\frac 12$ of CB.  So the height is $6$.

Comment: Yeah, you probably did.  I didn't read your answer when I posted either of my comments.

Comment: 30-60-90 is a special kind of triangle?

Comment: [trigonometry - Why is $\sin 30^\circ=\frac{1}{2}$ - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881520/why-is-sin-30-circ-frac12) -- no question for $\cos{30^\circ}$ that I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the angle is 30° is the giveaway. If you drop the perpendicular of $C$ onto $AB$ so the foot is $E$, $\triangle CEB$ is half of an equilateral triangle. It follows that the height $CE$ is half of $CB$, or 6, and the whole area follows.

Comment: Well, how you know that the triangle CEB is a half of an equilateral triangle? is a special kind of triangle or something? And why CE is half of CB, what is that property? thanks

Comment: @Mattiu If I place two copies of $CEB$ together I get a triangle whose angles are all 60°. Thus equilateral.

Comment: This is clearly the intended solution. I might want to pick a bone with the original problem poser, arguing that knowledge about the $30-60-90$ triangle is really (primitive) trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a trapezoid is given by $$A=h\cdot\frac{a+c}{2}$$ where $h$ is the height, $a$ is the lower base, $c$ is the upper base. In your case this it's $a=|AB|,c=|CD|$. We have those lengths given, so all that remains is the height $h$. Now consider a line $l$ going through point $C$ perpendicular to $AB$, denote the intersection point of $l$ and $AB$ for example $X$ then $\Delta XBC$ is a triangle with right angle at $X$. The height of the trapezoid is then $|XC|=h$. By elementary trigonometry $$\sin{30°}=\frac{1}{2}$$ also  $$\sin{\alpha=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}}$$
which in this case is
$$\sin{30°}=\frac{|XC|}{|BC|}=\frac{h}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$$
from which you get that $h=6$ and so your area is then 
$$A=h\cdot\frac{a+c}{2}=6\cdot\frac{30+8}{2}=114$$

Comment: Thank you, but clearly I have requested a solution without trigonometry

Comment: Well, what do you mean by solution with trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

So start with drawing a perpendicular line on AB which connects point C, making that a new point on line AB called point "E". Do the same thing on the left side by making another point on line AB called the point "F". Now you have a rectangle proving DC : FE and DF : CE. Both sides measuring 8. If you subtract AB - FE and divide the answer with 2, you now have the the measure for AF : BE which is 11. As CB = 12 you can now use Pythagorean Theorem to get measures of  DF and CE.BC^2 - BE^2 = CE^2, the square root √(BC^2 - BE^2) = CE. √(12^2 - 11^2) = 4.795831523. 
Area of Trapezoid = ((30+8)÷2)4.795831523)
                                 = 91.12079894

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Alan, you can not be sure that the segments are equal, that is, they measure 11. So this answer is wrong

Comment: I really don't know why but if I put these measures from you diagram in a Google based Area of Trapezoid calculator I get the same answer that I got.