# Is there any reason/intuition behind this pattern for exact values of sine?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, intuition

It's not hard to find the exact values of sine for the angles $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. But it always amazed me how there seems to be some sort of pattern when written like this:

\begin{align*}
\sin(0^\circ)&=\dfrac{\sqrt{0}}{2}\\
\sin(30^\circ)&=\dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
\sin(45^\circ)&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\sin(60^\circ)&=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\sin(90^\circ)&=\dfrac{\sqrt{4}}{2}\\
\end{align*}

Is this just a pure coincidence or is there something more mysterious hidden underneath? If the latter, what kind of intuition is there to understand such a pattern?

Comment: I mean... is there a pattern for the numbers $0,\, 30,\,45,\,60,\,90$, other than being the measure in degrees of the angles whose sines most children are forced to learn?

Comment: The main "deep" thing is that for angles $x$ in the first quadrant measured in degrees, $\sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos(x)^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin(90^\circ-x)^2}$. This gets you a lot of the way there, but it doesn't get you to why $30^\circ$ is special.

Comment: Suggestion: try using the half-angle formula to fill in some missing gaps, for example $\sin(15^\circ)$. Perhaps you'll see that patterns become harder to justify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883682/888233)

Comment: [How to intuitively understand how the trig ratios are calculated](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17863/372)

Answer (score 2):

As noticed in the comments, a reason behind comes from:

- the fundamental identity $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta=1$
- the symmetry identity $\cos \theta = \sin\left(90°-\theta\right)$

and therefore

- $\sin^2 90° = 1 - \sin^2 0° \iff \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{4}}{2}\right)^2=1-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{0}}{2}\right)^2$
- $\sin^2 60° = 1 - \sin^2 30° \iff \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2=1-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{2}\right)^2$
- $2\sin^2 45° = 1 \iff  \sin 45°=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$